# O Classpath do meu shell script não conseguiu achar um determinado jar

Tags: java, shell-script

Tenho um shell script que executa as seguintes instruções:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -classpath .:lib/* br.com.governa.admin.sincronizador.negocio.Sincronizador config/sincronizacao-espec-transparencia.xml
```

Hora que executo meu script ele está apresentando o seguinte erro:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at br.com.governa.admin.sincronizador.persistencia.BancoConexao.<init>(BancoConexao.java:39)
at br.com.governa.admin.sincronizador.negocio.Sincronizador.run(Sincronizador.java:113)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Porém o jar do sqlserver está na pasta lib

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo.. alguém pode me dar uma luz aí??

Comment: O caminho para a pasta `lib` é relativo. Esta pasta está realmente localizada como um subdiretório do diretório corrente quando você executa o script?

Comment: está sim @utluiz meu script está um diretório pra cima da lib... eu estou usando uma classe(br.com.governa.admin.sincronizador.negocio.Sincronizador) desse jar (governa-admin-sincronizador-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar) que está na mesma pasta lib

Comment: Mesmo assim se estiver executando de outro diretório o que conta é o diretório corrente e não onde está localizado o script. Já tentou mudar para um caminho absoluto?

Comment: vou tentar aqui... valeu

Comment: @utluiz movi o script para a pasta lib e executei la de dentro continuou com o erro :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: Pelo nome da classe, ela deveria estar contida no arquivo `sqljdbc4-4.0.jar`. Verifique se o jar não está corrompido e a classe realmente está nesse jar. Também notei que você tem o driver do JTDS, que é uma alternativa *opensource* ao oficial da Microsoft. Há algum motivo para ter os dois drivers no classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Por algum motivo especifico no linux a linha onde estava com a informação que usa esse driver pra acessar o banco de dados,  tinha espaço em branco devido a eu mandar formatar com o atalho CTRL + SHIFT + F e no windows ele ignora o espaço e funciona corretamente, foi só tirar o espaço em branco funcionou beleza!